# Is it bad practise to use get() on an Optional?

Tags: nullreferenceexception, java-stream, option-type

I want to sum the first thousand prime numbers. When I try this...

```
System.out.println(getFirstThousandPrimes().stream()
                                           .reduce(Integer::sum)
                                           .get()
    );
```

IntelliJ suggests me to check isPresent(), but is that even possible?

Another option would be to use .orElse(-1), but I don't want to return anything. Should I throw an Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular test having empty input is perfectly valid: sum of zero numbers is zero. So you can use `.reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0)` or completely get rid of optionals like `.reduce(0, Integer::sum)`.

Also note that you may convert to primitive stream and use `sum()` method directly:

```
getFoos().stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum();
```

This way you will of course also get 0 if the input is empty.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessarily a bad practice to use `.get()` without `.ifPresent`.  It comes down to the logic that you are implementing.  If empty `Optional` is an exceptional condition, it's perfectly appropriate to rely on `.get()` to throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

So the question you should ask yourself is what exactly should your code do if `getFirstThousandPrimes()` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

By reducing stream into argument there is a possibility that the stream will be empty and the `Optional` is introduced to handle this case. There's one more reduce() method which accepts identity argument and thus reduce `Optional`returned because in case of empty stream the identity will be returned.

But focusing on your task, I would recommend using custom collector to partition prime and non-prime numbers and then to sum first n numbers.

Some time ago I implemented the collector of prime and non-prime numbers and the implementation looks like the following:

```
public class PrimeNumberCollector implements Collector<Integer,
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>,
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> {

@Override
public Supplier<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> supplier() {
    return () -> new HashMap<Boolean, List<Integer>>() {{
        put(Boolean.TRUE, new ArrayList<>());
        put(Boolean.FALSE, new ArrayList<>());
    }};
}

@Override
public BiConsumer<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>, Integer> accumulator() {
    return (Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> acc, Integer candidate) -> acc.get(isPrime(candidate))
            .add(candidate);
}

@Override
public BinaryOperator<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> combiner() {
    return (Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> firstMap, Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> secondMap) -> {
        firstMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).addAll(secondMap.get(Boolean.TRUE));
        firstMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).addAll(secondMap.get(Boolean.FALSE));

        return firstMap;
    };
}

@Override
public Function<Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>, Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>> finisher() {
    return Function.identity();
}

@Override
public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));
}

private static boolean isPrime(final int candidate) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(candidate)).noneMatch(i -> candidate % i == 0);
}
}
```

And its usage:

```
@Test
public void collectingPrimeNumbersWithCustomCollector() {
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> primesNumbersMap = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1_000_000)
            .boxed()
            .collect(CustomCollectors.primeNumbers()); //or new PrimeNumbersCollector()

    Utils.printLine("Prime numbers between 1 - 1_000_000:");
    Utils.printLine(primesNumbersMap.get(Boolean.TRUE));
}
```

You could then `limit(1000)` and `sum(0, BinaryOperator)` all the primes until reaching the count limit.

Alternatively, you could use the following method to filter the stream of numbers to select only primes and sum them:

```
 private static boolean isPrime(final int candidate) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(candidate)).noneMatch(i -> candidate % i == 0);
    }
```

The usage would look like the following:

```
Stream.iterate(1L, i -> i + 1) //iterate with sequential numbers
                .filter(MyFancyClass::isPrime)
                .limit(1000)
                .reduce(0L, Long::sum);
```

The second approach is more concise and efficient than the first one.

Hope this answers your question.